# Service Error when accessing windows azure DB from windows phone

Tags: web-services, entity-framework, windows-phone-7, azure, azure-storage

receiving the error:

The EntitySet 'User' is not defined in the EntityContainer 'festDBEntities'. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 46.

my app code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using FestCloud.festDBService;

namespace FestCloud
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private Service1Client _serviceClient;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _serviceClient = new Service1Client();
            _serviceClient.LoginUserCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginUserCompletedEventArgs>(_serviceClient_LoginUserCompleted);
        }

        void _serviceClient_LoginUserCompleted(object sender, LoginUserCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Error == null) && (e.Result != null))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + e.Result + " !");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not log in. Please check user name/password and try again.");
            }
        }

        private void logInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _serviceClient.LoginUserAsync(userNameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Text);
        }

        private void newAccountButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Register.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

and my service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace CloudServiceRole
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void AddUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            using (var context = new festDBEntities())
            {
                context.AddToUsers(new User()
                {
                    UserName = userName,
                    Password = password,

                });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public string LoginUser(string username, string password)
        {
            string query = @"SELECT value User.UserName FROM festDBEntities.User AS User WHERE User.UserName = @username AND User.Password = @password";

            ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[2];

            parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("username", username);
            parameters[1] = new ObjectParameter("password", password);

            using (var context = new festDBEntities())
            {
                ObjectQuery<string> results = context.CreateQuery<string>(query, parameters);

                foreach (string result in results)
                {
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null; ;
        }
    }
}
```

my IService.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace CloudServiceRole
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void AddUser(string userName, string password);

        [OperationContract]
        string LoginUser(string userName, string password);
        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    } 
}
```

My DB contains UserId(int)-PK, UserName(nvarchar), Password(nvarchar)
with others to be added after I get basics working.
any ideas on whats causing the error or my code in general?
Many thanks,MH

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a problem with the phone calling it, have you tried calling it from something else?  Have you tried calling a web service without parameters to see if that works?

You may want to check out this sample to get you started:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/hosting-wcf-service-in-windows-azure-and-consuming-in-window-7-phone-app/

Also, I would suggest WCF REST and returning JSON like:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/how-to-consume-wcf-rest-service-returning-json-in-windows-ph/

Comment: Can't get my head around JSON, have to go through my Web Service and find the issue, have removed the DB functionality from my project for now, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an Entity Framework issue. The most likely cause is the festDBEntities class doesn’t contain a property named User(Perhaps it is named Users?). Please check your object model first. From my experience, you can also write a LINQ query instead of an object query. LINQ query is strongly typed, and can help us to remove such errors at compile time.

In addition, please also add Entity Framework to the tags so more Entity Framework experts will involve in this thread to provide further suggestions.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: `User` is the table name in the DB so `User.UserName` should access the UserName column? Added the entity-framework tag as suggested and will look into the LINQ option

Comment: Users are being created as I just checked the database contents but logging them in is causing issue

Comment: If we search the error message, we will find the most likely cause is the entity set’s name is incorrect. So please check if it is indeed named “User”. It is not needed to check your database. Please check the object model generated by Entity Framework. The name in the object model may be different from that in the database.

It is also recommended to use LINQ instead of Entity SQL. With LINQ, if the name is incorrect, you’ll be notified at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: I am playing with LINQ at the moment but it is quite new to me

Comment: Can LINQ be used to add to a DB as well as consume from it? Checked my Model, Its called User

Comment: LINQ with Entity Framework supports full CRUD. Actually if you're getting started with Entity Framework, it is recommended to use LINQ instead of Entity SQL, as LINQ is much easier to implement. Most getting started tutorials talk about LINQ rather than Entity SQL. For example:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx